# Un verbe positif qualifiant le sens de l'ouïe

Tags: vocabulaire

Il existe un verbe positif qualifiant chacun de nos sens, mais il me manque celui qualifiant une écoute agréable.

- La vue : j'admire
- Le toucher : je caresse
- L'odorat : j'hume
- Le goût : je déguste
- L'ouïe : je ___ ?

Auriez-vous une idée ?

Comment: Question intéressante !

A part **écouter**, je ne trouve pas de verbe spécifique à l'ouïe, mais **j'apprécie** un opéra, **je profite** du bruit de la mer, etc...

En y réfléchissant, je pense que c'est pareil en anglais.

J'attends impatiemment de voir si quelqu'un trouve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne pense pas, effectivement, qu'il y ait un verbe spécifique (à part "écouter") en Français moderne. L'ouïe était associée au verbe "ouïr" en Français plus ancien.

Answer (score 3):

Je sais que "percevoir" marche pour tous nos sens et qu'il ne s’agit toujours pas des perceptions agréables, mais les animaux perçoivent très bien les sons et pour eux et leur défense ça peut être un point agréablement positif!  Mais je ne vois pas un seul mot/verbe carrément positif pour ce que nous faisons avec nos oreilles, donc bravo pour cette question intéressante !

Par contre, la phrase « sweet music to the ears » existe en anglais pour exprimer à-peu-près l’idée, donc peut-être un verbe plus cette phrase peut marcher : « Je l’entends comme une douce musique aux oreilles ».

(NB, s'il vous plait: I realize that my "answer" is really no answer at all and that it's actually a "comment," but I lack the "reputation" to make comments, so please be gentle with the downvotes!)

Comment: +1 [entendre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entendre), percevoir par l'oreille.